# Blank SMS appear on MobileSMS app

Tags: iphone, sms, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi

I'm building for a jail-broken device and I want to block incoming messages.

So I blocked it and delete it, but when I open MobileSMS ("Messages") app or biteSMS app, the message that was blocked is empty but the Sender still appears.

How can I completely delete this message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to hook this functions by 'theos'.:

```
- (void)_ingestIncomingCTMessage:(id)arg1
-(void) _processReceivedMessageWithInfo:(struct __CFDictionary *)arg1
-(void)_receivedMessage:(CKSMSRecordRef)message replace:(BOOL)replace
```

they are in SMSCTServer and SMSService.try them~~

Comment: I used it, but can't remove blocked SMS perfectly

Comment: you can directly return in the function - (void)_ingestIncomingCTMessage:(id)arg1.I try it on IOS 5.1.1 the SMS never appear~

Comment: I added SMSCTServer.framework and #import <SMSCTServer/SMSCTServer.h> but when it done my project error <AddressBook/AddressBook.h> no such file .... and SMSCTServer.framework is not found. Many help.

Comment: I use theos tool.can you give me more detailed info about your error.by now i think you should check your header files

Comment: Can you send me file header? I download SMSCTServer framework from this: https://github.com/mattlawer/iOS5-Private-Frameworks/blob/master/SMSCTServer/SMSCTServer.h 
When I added it, my project error at Addressbook.framework, I don't know???? 
How to use it?

Comment: sorry, i am so late.give me your mail address please~

Comment: trinhtuanstorm@gmail.com
Happy Lunar New Year :D

Comment: sorry,we are in Spring Festival,i am in china.but i download it from github.its name is rpetrich-iphoneheader,search.if you have some mistake in the futher,please @ me~~

Comment: I can't find that header, can you send me plz :D

Comment: Can you send me throught my email, I can't find it !?!?!

Comment: I have send it to trinhtuanstorm@gmail.com ~~~